# Promise/then for array of functions

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an array of functions such as:

```
let funcs = []
funcs.push(() => {window.x = fetch()})
funcs.push(() => {console.log(window.x)})
funcs.push(() => {console.log("Hello, world!")})
```

I would like the functions to be evoked one after the other, as in:

```
for (let func of funcs) {
  func();
}
```

However, I would like to concatenate the functions as if they were Promises so that the N+1 function is only ever invoked when the N function is resolved.

Comment: If you want them to act like promises, then make them return promises. You don't get the behaviour of promises otherwise.

Comment: @snnsnn — `reduce` won't help. There's still no way to tell when the first function is finished.

Comment: @Quentin I don't know whether the functions will be promises or not, that's the challenging bit. :)

Comment: @EdgarDerby — If the function doesn't provide a means for you to tell when it is done, then you can't tell when it is done.

Comment: When do you consider `window.x = fetch()` "resolved"? After `window.x` has been assigned or after the `fetch()` has settled into a response object? (Or even after the response body has been consumed?)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen After fetch has been fullfilled.

Comment: @EdgarDerby Then you must make that function return a promise which does not fulfill earlier than that.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your functions involve asynchronous operations and you must make clear when you consider such a function "resolved". More precisely, if you want to wait for a certain result, your function must return a promise for that result. For example, `fetch` returns a promise for a response object:

```
funcs.push(() => {return window.x = fetch(...)});
```

but you could alternatively wait for the response body to be completely consumed:

```
funcs.push(() => {return window.x = fetch(...).then(r => r.text())});
```

Synchronous functions like your second and third need not return anything.

With that you can use the following code to execute them one after another:

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve();
for (const func of funcs) promise = promise.then(func);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#return_value), `fetch()` will return `Promise`, so it will print `Hello, world!` first instead of value of `window.x` because `window.x` is `Promise`. So, you must resolve the fetch response first before printing it with the `async` function like this:

```js
let funcs = []
funcs.push(() => {
  window.x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/carts/1')
    .then(result => resolve(result.json()))
    .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
});
funcs.push(async() => { console.log(await window.x) });
funcs.push(() => { console.log("Hello, world!") });

(async() => {
  for (let func of funcs) {
    await func();
  }
})()
```

Comment: The use of the `Promise` constructor is totally unnecessary here. `window.x = fetch('https://dummyjson.com/carts/1').then(result => result.json())` suffices.

Answer (score -1):

You can mix "normal" functions with functions returning promises in your `funcs` array, but you will have to make sure that the promise (if there is one ...) is actually `returned` by the generating function and not only generated. I removed the curly braces (`{`,`}`) around your first function and also made sure that it returned a "sensible" value at the end (by supplying a further `.then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>window.x=d.username)` to it).

Once the `funcs` array is set up you can run the indivudual function *consecutively* in an `async` function by using the `await` keyword like this:

```js
const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"; // public API for testing ...
let funcs = [
 () => fetch(url+3).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>window.x=d.username), // returns a promise
 () => {console.log(window.x+` is the same as global x: ${x}`)},    // returns nothing
 () => {console.log("Hello, world!")} ];                            // returns nothing
async function doit(fns){ for (let fn of fns) await fn() }
doit(funcs);
```

It is generally *not* a good idea to work with a global variable like `window.x`. I only included it here in order to show that theoretically your approach can be made to work. However, a better way to get the result of a promise would be to return the desired value by the last chained `then()` method and pick it up by an expression that waits for it with `await`. But, of course, then your second function would also need to be changed in order *not* to be working with the global `x` but with a given argument `val`:

```js
const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"; // public API for testing ...
let funcs = [
 () => fetch(url+3).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>d.username), // returns a promise
 (val) => {console.log(`This is val: ${val}`)},            // returns nothing
 () => {console.log("Hello, world!")} ];                   // returns nothing
async function doit(fns){ 
 let v;
 for (let fn of fns) v=await fn(v); // v gets re-evaluated each time!
}
doit(funcs);
```